# When does a pseudo-Riemannian manifold have an always positive norm Killing field?

Tags: general-topology, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

When does a pseudo-Riemannian manifold have an always positive norm Killing field? (you may assume that the isometry group is of the form $SO(1,n)$ if necessary)

---

In the context of general relativity one would need the pseudo-Riemannian manifold to satisfy this constraint for it to be modelling the space-time. Then this always positive norm Killing field can be thought of as the "time".

Comment: Why on earth is this question getting negative votes!?

Comment: Maybe people think the question is too physics-oriented? No clue.

Comment: Maybe because it's your 31st question on the site and the entirety of the question is "I guess the general relativity motivations behind this are obvious...". The written question should contain the question.

Comment: Technical question/concern:  is this *really* a necessary condition for a pseudo-Riemannian metric of Lorentz type to represent a space-time?  Or just a *certain class* of possible space-times?  Seems like a good question to me, however, ***plus one!***; I guess I got here after the edits were performed. (I observe the question body contains the title question at this point.)  Season's Greetings!

Comment: The statement
"In the context of general relativity one would need the pseudo-Riemannian manifold to satisfy this constraint for it to be modelling the space-time."
is just plain wrong physically. Admitting an everywhere time-like Killing vector field tells you that the universe is stationary, which is very far from our human experience of a very _dynamic_ universe.